# WordPress Multisite installation different subdirectories

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to install WordPress with the multisite feature.  I've been able to successfully install it, but I haven't been able to get it to work in my directory structure.  I completely uninstalled WP, with the intention to reinstall after figuring out if it is possible to do the following (and, most importantly, how):

I'd like to manage two different blogs on the same domain (mydomain.com). So, when I did my first install, I used a path-based network (i.e. sub-directories), which I still think is the correct approach. However, with the path-based approach, my setup would not allow me to have the two blogs in completely different subdirectories.  For example, if I installed WP in mydomain.com/public, then I would have one blog at that address and any other blog I wanted to manage would have to have a URL with mydomain.com/public as a common path (e.g. mydomain.com/public/mysecondblog).

For this reason, I moved the installation to my root directory since every address as that in common.  However, that by default creates a blog instance in the installation location, and I do not want one in my root directory (i.e. at mydomain.com).  A second problem I encountered was that even with the installation in my root directory, I could not create a blog instance in several levels below it.  For example, I could create a blog instance at mydomain.com/blog/ and my domain.com/cars, but I could not create one at mydomain.com/cars/blog.

Basically, what I would like to achieve is to manage two blogs. One at mydomain.com/blog and one at mydomain.com/cars/blog.  I can't imagine this would NOT be possible.  It seems simple, but I cannot get it to work through the configurations I found in the codex and online.  Any help in achieving this simple, but somehow unattainable feat would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve this by manual installation of wordpress.

1) At your root level, make two folders by name "blog" & "cars".
2) Under your "cars" folder, create another folder by name "blog".

This will be http://yourdomain/blog & http://yourdomain/cars/blog

Now upload wordpress files under both the folders i.e. under "blog" and another "blog" (of cars).

Create two databases and connect it to these domains using wp-config.php ([Find here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) more info

Enjoy :-)

If you are facing any issues, write here and I will help you further..

Comment: This is two separate installations of WordPress is it not? If I do this, will I be able to manage the two separate blogs through one login (e.g. the multisite feature)?

Comment: Oh You want to have multisite feature. I've found exciting tutorial with screenshots here in this http://todaymade.com/blog/wordpress-multisite/